# Highlight values and save

Tags: r, svg, time-series, hover, plotly

I am using plotly to zoom my plots, save to svg and show most interesting intervals to customers. The thing I can't reach - I need to save picture with hover showing values.

For example, I zoomed, I pointed value I need to show, I see values using hover.

[image]

But when I press "Download plot" button - It's saved without hover information. Here is what I see in svg:

[image]

How can I show values on saved plots?

Here is my example code:

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

fig
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know any thing about the software/code you are using but as a general logic you have some different approaches to solve this.

1-create a function to take a screenshot of the area you have on screen with those hovering elements and save it as a bitmap image. This is valid just if you don't require to save/download your plot as an svg file.

2- In case you need to export as svg then you have to create a function to observe and get the svg code which is displaying your plot at the moment of hovering, then save the whole stuff as svg file.

3-If what you require is to save the plot as a svg file then it is also possible that the hovering effect along with the code to produce the highlighted content, to be exported inside the svg. The only means most users have t visualize an svg file is via web browser, so when the parts conteining hovering are hovered they will show the effect and the information.

As I said, these are just general logic to try to find out a solution.

Comment: I am using R and plotly - see tags to my post.

Comment: Sorry, the letters are too small for me right now. Any way I do not know a thing about R or Plotty and just gave you a general logic to follow further